# Sorting and catch the not expecting values (Shell Scripting)

Tags: text-processing, aix

I have a .csv file where I am expecting only YES and NO values in third column:

```
Sample1|Sample2|YES
Sample1|Sample2|YES
Sample1|Sample2|YES
Sample1|Sample2|YES
Sample1|Sample2|NO
Sample1|Sample2|MAYBE(random*)
Sample1|Sample2|MAYBE(random*)
```

Note: `(random*)` stands for random values that may be here.

So my desired output should be:

```
Expecting value count: 5
YES = 4
NO = 1

Not expecting value count: 2
MAYBE = 2
```

If there are no other values than YES and NO, my desired output should be:

```
Expecting value count:
YES = 4
NO = 1
Not expecting value count: 0
```

Comment: show the output of `awk --version`

Comment: Hi sir @RomanPerekhrest. When typing awk —version awk illegal option

Comment: John, I've edited your post to attempt to clarify the meaning -- mainly to include the last line of output into the code box. I've also tried to clarify the `random*` text, but if I got any of that wrong, please edit the post to clarify.

Comment: John do any of the answers solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like:

```
tr '(' '|' < file | cut -d'|' -f3 | sort | uniq -c
```

Comment: Yes that’s working for counting the values of column 3. The problem is how do i filter unexpected values. Please see the desired outputs

Answer (score 0):

```bash
for i in $(cat l.txt  | awk -F "|" '{print $3}' | sort | uniq); do
  grep -c $i l.txt;
  echo $i;
done | sed "N;s/\n/ /g"
```

l.txt contains content which you mentioned. Output is

```
2 MABYE(random)
1 NO
4 YES
```

For counting expected and unexpected you can save the output in file and use below command for expected on the output file for the previous command.

```bash
egrep -i "NO|YES" |
awk '{print $1}' |
tr "\n"  " " |
awk '{print "echo" " " $1 " " "+" " " $2 }' |
sed 's/^/"/g' |
sed 's/$/"/g' |
awk '{print $0"|bc -l"}' |
sed 's/"echo/echo "/g' |
sh
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an AIX-compatible awk solution:

```
BEGIN {
  FS="|";
}
{
  values[$3]++
}
END {
  print "Expecting value count: " values["YES"] + values["NO"];
  print "YES = " values["YES"];
  print "NO = " values["NO"];
  delete values["YES"];
  delete values["NO"];
  for (value in values)
    unexpected += values[value];
  if (unexpected) {
    print "\nNot expecting value count: " unexpected;
    for (value in values)
      print value " = " values[value];
  }
}
```

Save that to a script named whatever you want.

For this sample input:

```
Sample1|Sample2|YES
Sample1|Sample2|YES
Sample1|Sample2|YES
Sample1|Sample2|YES
Sample1|Sample2|NO
Sample1|Sample2|MAYBE1
Sample1|Sample2|MAYBE2
Sample1|Sample2|MAYBE2
```

... the output is:

```
$ awk -f i.awk < input
Expecting value count: 5
YES = 4
NO = 1

Not expecting value count: 3
MAYBE1 = 1
MAYBE2 = 2
```

... and for this sample input:

```
Sample1|Sample2|YES
Sample1|Sample2|NO
Sample1|Sample2|NO
```

... the output is:

```
$ awk -f i.awk < input2
Expecting value count: 3
YES = 1
NO = 2
Not expecting value count: 0
```